# Handling Post Requests

Tags: php

I wrote this, and wanted to get everyones opinion. I use this when I'm expecting a variable from a FORM submission. Ie:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
</form>
```

```
$username = get_request('username');

function get_request($name) {
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$name])) {
        //return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_REQUEST[$name]));
        return mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$name]);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you expect the data to be passed as a POST variable you can use the $_POST array.

Comment: I suggest using `$_POST` or `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While mysql_real_escape_string() does a good job, you may wish to be stricter on what you return. E.g. if you only need alphanumeric characters it would be safer (and possibly faster) to do:

```
return preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', $_REQUEST[$name]);
```

Or even use [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) if you are running PHP 5.2+.

Also as mentioned above, you if you can easily use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST if you are only handling POST data.

Other than than that, keep up the good work! :)

Answer (score 1):

Nice, but shouldn't you want to return an error instead of an empty string if the $_REQUEST fails? Otherwise good!

Answer (score 1):

It looks OK, except it won't help you against certain SQL injections. You should add another argument to your function that sanitizes input according to types, for instance to make sure your return is an integer or a floating point number.

If for instance you have a pagination mechanism with a query `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 10, $page`. If `$page` = `like 1; DROP TABLE tbl --` and it gets send through your function `get_request()`, it won't help you any bit.

Another thing is you should just return null instead of an empty string (`""`) if it doesn't exist.

If you for instance have a variable `$x = ""`, then `isset($x)` will return `true`, whereas it would return false with `$x = null`.

And as other people have pointed out, you should distinguish between `GET` and `POST`.